# New Mac lost Rstudio Admin Privileges

Tags: macos, administrator, rstudio

I got a new macbook and migrated my applications and files over. I have a new user but everything else is the same.

I tried to install a package in Rstudio and it returned an error

> Installation path not writeable

Turns out when I look at Tools>install packages the library path points to a directory that doesn't exist. `.libpaths()` shows I have two directories, but I cannot access the correct one without admin privileges, which Rstudio apparently no longer has. Running `sudo /Applications/RStudio\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio` in terminal works to solve this, but I don't want to have to do this every time. Also, re-downloading Rstudio does not help

How do I either grant Rstudio permanent admin privileges, or change the library path for package install? Thanks